# Change System.Windows.Controls.Image to MemoryStream?

Tags: silverlight, c#-4.0

I have a problem in silverlight which I need to convert this image(from database probably will be in bytes) and convert it to MemoryStream. I need to do this so I can use it to export images to PDF files. Any Ideas?

```
Image myImage = new Image();
myImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Resources/cancel.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

For starters, I am trying to convert an Image object to a memory stream object in a sample project(that's why UriSource is coded). Because I'm not familiar with creating dummy data in bytes. Any help on this one? Can I convert an Image to MemoryStream? if not, I believe bytes can be converted to stream, how can I do dummy data?

Thanks for all the replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to pass byte[] to [MemoryStream constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e55f3s5k.aspx)

```
byte[] bytes = GetBytes();
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
```

Hope this helps